# Null Value not getting stored in database of column type datetime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

So here is portion of the code:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strStartDate.ToString()))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_start_date", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_start_date", strStartDate);
}
```

Note: Yes, the column is nullable in the database. It is of type "DateTime"

Yes, the DateTime is declared as nullable in the actual project as well. Looks like this:

```
public datetime? strStartDate {get; set;}
```

So the entire function is big but this is the part that I am having trouble with. If the second condition executes, this means that the entered value is a proper value. The result is stored in the database. However, if the first condition is executed, I don't even get an error, it just says "successfully added" which is a modal that is supposed to show after the form is submitted.

In other words, both conditions execute and show no error, however, if the first condition is executed, it does not store anything at all in that whole row. The row does not exist in sql. I am sorry if I have confused anyone but I have been having trouble with this the whole day.

Comment: `strStartDate` is not a string, don't treat it like one.

Comment: So how can I store the value as null, if nothing is picked in the form? The form has a datetimepicker. Also I made an edit look again. I forgot to add ToString() before

Comment: `if (!strStartDate.HasValue))`

Comment: Also, recommended reading: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195952/1288

Comment: Wait what is the difference between `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strStartDate.ToString()))` and `if (!strStartDate.HasValue))` in this situation?

Comment: sql server 2008 is really old, maybe an update would be i order

Comment: I suspect the problem has to do with the DateTimePicker and how you're transferring that value to `strStartDate`.  If nothing else, what does the debugger show happening?

Comment: if `strStartDate` is `null` then `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strStartDate.ToString()))` is going to throw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert `datetime` to `string` in if

By default DBType of `SqlParameter` is `String`

Use `Add` overload method instead of `AddWithValue`

```
if (strStartDate == null)
{
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@job_start_date",
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                        Value = DBNull.Value
                    });
}
else
{
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@job_start_date",
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                        Value = strStartDate 
                    });
}
```

Done!

Comment: Better yet ax the if/else and just do `Value = (object?)strStartDate ?? DBNull.Value`

Comment: Error is not to set the `null` value. Error is to set `datatype` of that parameter and then set its value.